# Inserting C code between YACC grammar's rules creates shift/reduces conflicts

Tags: c, yacc, lex

Currently i am working on an assignement from my Formal Language and Compilers course and i am hitting a constant wall which is,when i am inserting C code between rules literals a lot of shift/reduces appears.For example let's say that i have the following extracted from my grammar.

function_declaration: OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET list_param CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET ID available_types
                      OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET function_content CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET 
                    | OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET list_param CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET ID available_types 
                     OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET 
                    ;

If i am inserting something like

function_declaration: {add_new_node(head);}OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET list_param CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET ID 
                      available_types
                      OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET function_content CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET 
                    | OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET list_param CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET ID available_types 
                     OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET

This creates a shift/reduce .Why and how i can avoid this.

My entire code:

Grammar.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include </usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h>

extern FILE* yyin;
extern int yylineno;
int yydebug=1;
int yylex();
int yyerror(char *s);

typedef struct expr_info
{
        char*name;
        int datatype;
        int intvalue;
        float floatvalue;
        _Bool boolvalue;

} expr_info;
struct SymTabEntry
{
        char*name;
        char*scope;
        char*whatIs;
        char*dataType;
        int intvalue;
        int lineOf;
        char*stringval;
        char charvalue;
        float floatvalue;
        char*paramlist;

} SymTabEntry;
struct Checker
{
        GHashTable*localScope;
        int counter;
        char*currentScope;
        struct Checker*next;

};
GHashTable*SymTab;
int noScopes=0;
struct Checker*head=NULL;
void init_checker();
void free_entry(struct SymTabEntry*val);
void start_program();
void add_new_variable(struct Checker*head,const char*type,char*identifier);
const char*return_type(int type);
void dump_symtab(gpointer key,gpointer value,gpointer userdata);
void add_new_node(struct Checker*head);
void remove_head_node(struct Checker*head);
void printf_symtab();

%}

%union 
{
        int type;
        char*strname;
        int intval;
        char* strval;
        _Bool boolval;
        char charval;
        float floatval;
        struct expr_info* expr_ptr;
}

%start start_program
%token START END ASSIGN IF ELSEIF WHILE FOR STRCPY STRLEN STRCMP STRCAT ADD DIV BIGGER SMALLER MIN MUL EQUAL OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET INCR CLASS MAIN ELSE SMALLER_EQUAL BOOL_TRUE BOOL_FALSE GREATER_EQUAL STRING_TYPE CONST
%left ADD 
%left MIN
%left MUL
%left DIV
%left SMALLER
%left BIGGER
%left INCR
%left EQUAL
%left IF
%left ELSEIF


%token<strname> ID
%token<intval> INT_VAL;
%token<strval> STRING_VAL
%token<floatval> FLOAT_VAL
%token<charval> CHAR_VAL
%token<type> INT STRING FLOAT CHAR BOOL
%type<type> available_types 

%%
start_program:{init_checker(head);start_program();} declaration_section main_section {printf("Programul este corect\n");}
             ;

declaration_section:declaration_section declaration_content;
                    | declaration_content
                    ;

declaration_content: function_declaration 
                    | object_declaration  
                    | create_variable 
                    ;


object_declaration: ID CLASS OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET object_content CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET 
                   | ID CLASS OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET
                   ;

object_content:object_content inside_object 
              | inside_object
              | expression 
              ; 

inside_object:function_declaration
             | create_variable 
             ; 

function_declaration: OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET list_param CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET ID available_types  OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET function_content CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET 
                    | OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET list_param CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET ID available_types OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET 
                    ;

list_param:list_param ',' ID available_types
           |ID available_types
           ;

function_content: function_content instructions
                | instructions
                ;

multiple_instructions:multiple_instructions instructions
                     | instructions
                     ;

instructions: if_instr
            | while_instr
            | for_instr
            | assign_instr 
            | create_variable 
            | ';'function_call
            | ';' object_call_function
            ;

function_call:'#'OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET list_call CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET  ID
             |'#'OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET  ID
             ;


list_call: expression  ',' list_call
         | expression
         ;

if_instr:OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET expression CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET IF OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET multiple_instructions CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET else_instr
        |OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET expression CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET IF OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET else_instr
        ;

else_instr:ELSE OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET multiple_instructions CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET
          |ELSE OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET
          | 
          ;

while_instr: OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET expression CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET WHILE OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET multiple_instructions CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET
            |OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET expression CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET WHILE OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET
            ;

assign_instr: ';'expression ASSIGN ID 
            | ';'expression ASSIGN object_access_var
            | ';'expression ASSIGN access_vector
            ;


for_instr: OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET assign_instr ';' expression ';' expression CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET FOR OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET multiple_instructions CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET
         | OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET assign_instr ';' expression ';' expression CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET FOR OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET
         | OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET FOR OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET
         ;

create_variable: ';'create_single_variable 
             //  | ';''#'create_multiple_variable available_types
               | ';''$'create_array_variable
               | ';'create_const_variable
               ;

create_array_variable:'['expression']' ID available_types
                     | '[' expression ']' ID ID
                     ;

create_single_variable:  '$' ID available_types {add_new_variable(head,return_type($3),$2);}
                        |'$' ID ID {add_new_variable(head,$3,$2);}
                        |'$' expression ASSIGN ID available_types {add_new_variable(head,return_type($5),$4);}
                        |'$' expression ASSIGN ID ID {add_new_variable(head,$5,$4);}
                        |'$' expression ASSIGN ID available_types CONST {
                                char*newtype=malloc(strlen("const-")+strlen(return_type($5))+1);
                                strcpy(newtype,"const-");
                                strcat(newtype,return_type($5));
                                newtype[strlen(newtype)]='\0';
                                add_new_variable(head,newtype,$4);
                        }
                        ;
/*
create_multiple_variable:create_multiple_variable ',' ID
                        | ID
*/                     ;

create_const_variable:expression ASSIGN ID CONST available_types
                     | expression ASSIGN ID CONST ID
                     ;

available_types: INT {$$=$1;}
               | CHAR {$$=$1;}
               | FLOAT {$$=$1;}
               | BOOL {$$=$1;}
               | STRING {$$=$1;}
               ;

expression: ID 
          | INT_VAL 
          | FLOAT_VAL
          | BOOL_TRUE
          | BOOL_FALSE
          | STRING_VAL
          | function_call
          | object_call_function
          | object_access_var
          | access_vector
          | OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET expression CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET
          | expression ADD expression 
          | expression MUL expression
          | expression DIV expression
          | expression MIN expression
          | expression BIGGER expression
          | expression SMALLER expression
          | expression EQUAL expression
          | STRCPY OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET expression expression CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET
          | STRLEN OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET expression CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET
          | STRCAT OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET expression expression CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET
          ;


object_call_function:function_call '.' ID
                    ;

object_access_var:ID'.'ID
                 ;

access_vector:'['expression']' ID
             ;

main_section:OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET MAIN INT OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET multiple_instructions CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET
            | OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET MAIN INT OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET
            ;
%%
int yyerror(char * s){
    printf("eroare: %s la linia:%d\n",s,yylineno);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
   yyin=fopen(argv[1],"r");
   init_checker();
   yyparse();
   printf_symtab();
   return 0;
} 
void init_checker()
{
        head=malloc(sizeof(struct Checker));
        head->next=NULL;
        head->localScope=g_hash_table_new_full(g_str_hash,g_str_equal,g_free,(void*)free_entry);
        head->currentScope=malloc(2);
        strcpy(head->currentScope,"0");
        head->currentScope[strlen(head->currentScope)]='\0';
        head->counter=0;
}
void free_entry(struct SymTabEntry*val)
{
        g_free(val);
}
void start_program()
{
        SymTab=g_hash_table_new_full(g_str_hash,g_str_equal,g_free,(void*)free_entry);
}
void add_new_variable(struct Checker*head,const char*type,char*identifier)
{
        printf("Adaug:%s de tipul %s in cu path-ul %s\n",identifier,type,head->currentScope);
        struct SymTabEntry*newEntry=malloc(sizeof(struct SymTabEntry));
        newEntry->name=malloc(strlen(identifier)+1);
        newEntry->name[strlen(newEntry->name)]='\0';
        strcpy(newEntry->name,identifier);
        newEntry->dataType=malloc(strlen(type)+1);
        strcpy(newEntry->dataType,type);
        newEntry->whatIs=malloc(strlen("variable")+1);
        strcpy(newEntry->whatIs,"variable");
        newEntry->scope=malloc(strlen(head->currentScope));
        strcpy(newEntry->scope,head->currentScope);
        newEntry->lineOf=yylineno;
        g_hash_table_insert(head->localScope,identifier,newEntry);
}
const char*return_type(int type)
{
        switch(type)
        {
                case 0:{return "int";}
                case 1:{return "char";}
                case 2:{return "float";}
                case 3:{return "bool";}
                case 4:{return "char*";}
                case 5:{return "const";}
        }

}
void print_key_value(gpointer key,gpointer value,gpointer userdata)
{
        struct SymTabEntry*var=value;
        printf("%s \t%s\t %s \t %s\n",var->name,var->whatIs,var->dataType,var->scope);
}
void printf_symtab()
{
       g_hash_table_foreach(SymTab,print_key_value,NULL);
}
void add_new_node(struct Checker*head)
{
        printf("Am adaugat ceva nou\n");
        head->counter++;
        struct Checker*newChecker=malloc(sizeof(struct Checker));
        newChecker->currentScope=malloc(strlen(head->currentScope)+3);
        if(head->next==NULL)
        {

            sprintf(newChecker->currentScope,"%d",head->counter);
        }
        else
        {
                strcpy(newChecker->currentScope,head->currentScope);
                strcat(newChecker->currentScope,"-");
                char value[6];
                sprintf(value,"%d",newChecker->counter);
                strcat(newChecker->currentScope,value);   
        }
        newChecker->localScope=g_hash_table_new_full(g_str_hash,g_str_equal,g_free,(void*)free_entry);
        newChecker->next=head;
        head=newChecker;
}
void remove_head_node(struct Checker*head)
{

}
```

Lex.l

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%option noyywrap
%%
"/*"(.|\n)"*/" ;
"tni" {yylval.type=0;return INT;}
"ssalc" {return CLASS;}
"rahc" {yylval.type=1;return CHAR;}
"taolf" {yylval.type=2;return FLOAT;}
"loob" {yylval.type=3;return BOOL;}
"*rahc" {yylval.type=4;return STRING;}
"fi" {return IF;}
"esle" {return ELSE;}
"fiesle" {return ELSEIF;}
"elihw" {return WHILE;}
"tsnoc" {return CONST;}
"rof" {return FOR;}
"ypcrts" {return STRCPY;}
"nelrts" {return STRLEN;}
"pmcrts" {return STRCMP;}
"tacrts" {return STRCAT;}
"niam" {return MAIN;}
"eurt" {return BOOL_TRUE;}
"eslaf" {return BOOL_FALSE;}
"+" {return ADD;}
"-" {return MIN;}
"*" {return MUL;}
"/" {return DIV;}
">" {return BIGGER;}
"<" {return SMALLER;}
"<=" {return SMALLER_EQUAL;}
">=" {return GREATER_EQUAL;}
"++" {return INCR;}
"=" {return ASSIGN;}
"==" {return EQUAL;}
"{" {return OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET;}
"}" {return CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET;}
"(" {return OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET;}
")" {return CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET;}
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]* {yylval.strname=strdup(yytext);return ID;}
[-]?[1-9][0-9]*|0 {yylval.intval=atoi(yytext);return INT_VAL;}
[-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+ {yylval.floatval=atof(yytext);return FLOAT_VAL;}
\"[^\"\n]*\" {yylval.strval=strdup(yytext);return STRING_VAL;}
[ \t] ;
\n {yylineno++;}
. {return yytext[0];}
```

It is still incomplete and under wroking conditions.The thing that i am trying to achieve is a symbol table for verifying at run if for example the variable was declared before use and such.

Answer (score 1):

The code here, which you say produces a shift/reduce conflict, is not "between rules":

```
function_declaration
  : {add_new_node(head);} '(' list_param ')' ID available_types '{' function_content '}'
  | '(' list_param ')' ID available_types '{' '}'
```

(That's your rule except I replaced the tokens with [single-character literals](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#index-single_002dcharacter-literal) to reduce the line width.)

The action in that line is *inside* the rule, so it's a [mid-rule action](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Midrule-Actions), usually abbreviated MRA. MRAs are notorious for creating conflicts, and the bison manual has a whole section on [conflicts from MRAs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Midrule-Conflicts) and what you can do about them.

In fact, it includes an example pretty similar to yours: two rules which start with the same token, where one has a leading MRA and the other doesn't. As the manual says, the result is that

> …the parser is forced to decide whether to run the midrule action when it has read no farther than the open-brace. In other words, it must commit to using one rule or the other, without sufficient information to do it correctly.

It's not clear to my why you feel the need to have two productions in that example. You could easily combine them into a single production, either by left-factoring or by allowing `function_content` to be empty (i.e. replace the non-recursive rule `function_content: instructions` with `function-content: %empty`.

If only one rule is applicable, then there is no conflict. But that does mean that the MRA will also be called for function declarations with empty content. Frankly, I don't see any reason you'd want to avoid the call in that case, but you may well have your reasons.

For other approaches, see the bison manual sections I linked above.